# How to do the naming "of" construct in Chinese?

Tags: grammar, preposition

In English (or Spanish), you use "of" (and other prepositions), for doing complex names, such as people or place names in some cases:

- The seat of the great rock of the north.
- The man of the forest of the east.
- The super tall man of the great green forest of the far east.
- The man who was English and from the forest in the east before the river. (The man of English of the forest of the east of the river, to some degree).

How do you do this "of" in Chinese? Please add the pinyin in addition to the Chinese characters, so that I may see the literal gloss of the Chinese.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**of = ... 的** [dì;de]

- The seat of the great rock of the north. = The north('s) great rock's seat - 北方(**的**)巨石**的**基座/底盤.
- The man of the forest of the east. = The east('s) forest's man - 東方(**的**)叢林**的**男人.
- The super tall man of the great green forest of the far east. = The far east('s) great green forest's super tall man - 遠東(**的**)大叢綠林**的**超高男人.

Comment: I second r13's answer. A of B would be B 的 A. Notice also r13 put some of the 的s in parentheses. When there is more than 1 的 in a sentence it sounds kind of awkward in Chinese and only one is used. "The seat of the great rock of the north" would be expressed as "The seat of the great north rock". Similarly "The man of the east forest", The super tall man of the great far eastern green forest". It's not wrong to use more than one 的 but again it's a bit awkward. Even more than 1 "of" in English is a bit awkward. But to answer your question, 的 expresses "of".